# sorting out my horizontal bar chart in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, charts, bar-chart

I have been trying to visualize some data and put them on horizontal bar charts stacked over each other.

when doing so, I find it hard to sort them based on their sizes, which I wanted.

I have tried sorting the date before visualizing it but that didn't help.

could someone please help me sort them des.
thanks

```
import pandas as pd 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

plot3 = df.groupby(['Company', 'Outcome']).size()
plot3 = plot3.unstack()
plot3[:].sort_values(('Company'), axis = 0, ascending = True).plot(kind = 'barh',color = ['r', 'g'],figsize = [15, 10], stacked = True)
#df= df.sort_values('Company', axis = 0, ascending = True,inplace = True)
    
plt.savefig('plot3.png')'''



[![here is what i get][1]][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkvY9.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sorting summed rows by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `key` parameter and `scending=False`:

```
(plot3.sort_index(key=plot3.sum(axis=1).get, ascending=False)
      .plot(kind = 'barh',color = ['r', 'g'],figsize = [15, 10], stacked = True))
```

Or use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html), `-` for negative values is for descending order:

```
(plot3.iloc[-plot3.sum(axis=1).argsort()]
      .plot(kind = 'barh',color = ['r', 'g'],figsize = [15, 10], stacked = True))
```

Comment: just a follow up question, Can 'Outcome' be used to sort the values instead of 'Company' in `plot3[:].sort_values(('Company'), axis = 0, ascending = True).plot(kind = 'barh',color = ['r', 'g'],figsize = [15, 10], stacked = True)` ?

Comment: @micro5 - Not sure how is sorting necessary, seems by sum of counts. Your solution is not possible, because `plot3.unstack()`